Jinja2 multiple maps
Can someone help point to what I'm doing wrong in the following Jinja template? Since 'units' is a sequence, I though map(attribute='name') would iterate over each item in the list and extract the 'name' piece.
Expected output:["item1", "item2", "xyz", "mno"]
Actual output. : [Undefined,·Undefined]
{% set a = {
    "val1": {
        "name": "val1",
        "units": [
            {
                "name": "item1", "size": 45
            },
            {
                "name": "item2", "size": 36
            }
        ]
    },
    "val2": {
        "name": "val2",
        "units": [
            {
                "name": "xyz", "size": 45
            },
            {
                "name": "mno", "size": 36
            }
        ]
    },
    
}

            
%}
{% set check = a.values() | list | map(attribute='units') | map(attribute='name') | list  %} 


{{ check }}



Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

Problem is that outcome of
{% set check = a.values() | list | map(attribute='units') %}

is a list of lists (one list of dicts for each top-level key "val1" and "val2"), something like:
[[{'name': 'item1', 'size': 45}, {'name': 'item2', 'size': 36}], [{'name': 'xyz', 'size': 45}, {'name': 'mno', 'size': 36}]]

To get all unit names across these lists using map() you first need to merge those lists. You can conveniently use | sum(start=[]) in between both maps. That will start with empty list and merge lists of dicts together. Then you can use map(attribute='name') to finally get all names:
{% set check= a.values() | map(attribute='units') | sum(start=[]) | map(attribute='name') %}
{{ check | list }}

